# prove that 2 vectors is linearly independent in the vector space of vectors of length 2 with entries of real-valued functions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have the following vectors
$V_1=(e^t,te^t), V_2=(1,t)$ 
now I want to prove that this two vectors are linearly independent in the vector space of vectors of length 2 with entries of real-valued functions.

when I'm writing the formula:

$C_1*V_1^T+C_2*V_2^T=0$ and writing it in matrix notation I can't get to prove that the coefficients needs to be 0.

I do note that if I'm fixing t for a given value then they are linearly dependent which is somewhat weird because i know i need to prove that for general t they are not.

Would appreciate some thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the linear equations:

$$\begin{cases}I&c_1e^t+c_2=0\\{}\\II&c_1te^t+c_2t=0\end{cases}$$

The above two equations are true for **any** calue of $\;t\in\Bbb R\;$ (I'm assuming the functions are defined on the whole real line), so take some particular values:

$$t=0\stackrel I\implies c_1+c_2=0\implies c_2=-c_1\stackrel {II}\implies c_1t\left(e^t-1\right)=0$$

Take now $\;t=1\;$ and you get $\;c_1(e-1)=0\implies c_1=0\;$ and thus also $\;c_2=0\;$ and we're done.

Comment: so this is a valid proof, isn't any robust method for this kind of cases? i did it but for some reason it seems to simple for a proof

Comment: I can't see anything "robust" in this proof. It is just going by the very simple *definition* ...

Comment: Yeah i get that, but what if there were like k vectors, this would be the only way
cause if i can represent in a matrix and isolate the part that depends on t, then its just matrix reduction

Comment: @chemist I don't quite follow you. The above is a proof. Maybe there are other ones though I suspect not a simple and elementary as this one. If there were $\;k\;$ one could probably do the same, although then it would probably be a little more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Linear dependence of ${\bf v}_1$ and ${\bf v}_2$ in the vector space $X$ of functions ${\bf x}:\>t\mapsto\bigl(x_1(t),x_2(t)\bigr)$ means that there are *fixed* numbers $\lambda$, $\mu \in{\mathbb R}$, not both zero,  such that $$\lambda {\bf v}_1(t)+\mu {\bf v}_2(t)={\bf 0}\qquad\forall\> t\ .\tag{1}$$
Inspecting the first component of $(1)$ we obtain the condition $\lambda e^t+\mu=0$. This condition cannot be satisfied for all $t$ with fixed numbers $\lambda$, $\mu$, other than $\lambda=\mu=0$. It follows that the two given vectors are linearly independent in $X$.